# How do you calculate a probability when the Bernoulli probabilities don't total 1?

Tags: probability

Assume that events $(A, B)$ are disjoint and their probabilities are $a$ and $b$, respectively. $a + b \le 1$.

Trials are conducted until $A$ or $B$ occurs. Find the probability that $A$ occurs before $B$.

Comment: Please include your thoughts and efforts (work in progress) in this and future posts. 
You are more likely to receive positive/constructive feedback that way.  
Formatting your post helps too.
Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that the probabilities don't add to $1$ is actually unimportant - you simply have one or more further outcomes with total probability $1-a-b$.

Let $p$ be the probability that $A$ occurs before $B$.  This happens if

- $A$ occurs first; or
- neither $A$ nor $B$ occurs first, and then in the subsequent trials $A$ occurs before $B$.

Therefore
$$p=a+(1-a-b)p$$
and solving gives
$$p=\frac{a}{a+b}\ ,$$
which if you think about it is pretty much what you would expect intuitively.

Answer (score 0):

David gave the answer using *partitioning* the first trial, and the law of total probability.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(n_A{<}n_B) & = {\mathsf P(n_A{<}n_B\mid n_A{=}1)\mathsf P(n_A{=}1) \\ +\mathsf P(n_A{<}n_B\mid n_A{>}1, n_B{>}1)\mathsf P(n_A{>}1, n_B{>}1) \\ \color{silver}{+ \underbrace{P(n_A{<}n_B\mid n_B{=}1)}_{=0}\mathsf P(n_B{=}1)} } \\ p & = a+(1-a-b)p \\ \therefore p & = \frac{a}{a+b}\end{align}$$

---

Alternatively, the probability that $A$ occurs before $B$ is the probability that $A$ occurs on condition that either $A$ or $B$ occurs.

That is, we shall ignore all trials that don't result in $A$ or $B$, and determine the probability that $A$ occurs on the first trial that we don't ignore.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(n_A{<}n_B) & = \mathsf P(A\mid A\cup B) \\ & = \frac{\mathsf P(A)}{\mathsf P(A\cup B)} \\ & = \frac{a}{a+b}\end{align}$$